# Why does dependency injection not work when using the Koin library in Kotlin project

Tags: xamarin, kotlin, binding, xamarin.android, koin

I am trying to bind this Webtrekk library (https://github.com/Webtrekk/webtrekk-android-sdk-BETA) for Android
Webtrekk SDK is written in Kotlin and uses Koin for dependency injection. I am able to create biding and build it successfully but when I add a binding product to application dependency injection don't work.
Did someone try to bind Kotlin (with Koin library) SDK and use it in some Xamarin.Android application?
Is there any tutorial, example or documentation for that?